# How to read all text file with head linux command?

Tags: bash, shell

I can't read or apply any other commands like `cat` or `strings` on .txt files because it is not allowed. I need to read a file named flag.txt, but this file is also on the blacklist. So, is there any way to read *.txt using the `head` command? The `head` command is allowed.

```
blacklist=\
'flag\|<\|$\|"\|'"'"'\|'\
'cat\|tac\|*\|?\|less\|more\|pico\|nano\|edit\|hexdump\|xxd\|'\
'sed\|tail\|diff\|grep\|paste\|strings\|bas64\|sort\|uniq\|cut\|awk\|'\
'bzip\|gzip\|xz\|tar\|ar\|'\
'mv\|cp\|ln\|nl\|'\
'python\|perl\|sh\|cc\|g++\|php\|hd\|g++\|gcc\|curl\|tcp\|udp\|'\
'scp\|sftp\|wget\|nc\|netcat'
```

Thanks

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction on what programs you can use?

Comment: Maybe there is a reason why they don't let you to do that?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question but yes, you can output with `head -100 *.txt` first 100 lines of all `*.txt` files. You can find out the number of lines with `wc -l file` (not on your list) or use a ridiculous line value. You don't seem to have `rev` in the blacklist either, so you could `rev file | rev` also. Or use `ed`: `ed file` then press 5 to print line 5 of `file`.

Answer (score 0):

do you want some alternative of the command `head *.txt`? if so, `ls`/`find`and `xargs` will help, but it can not identify .txt file, it will read all the file under the directory.

```
ls -1| xargs head
```

Comment: we can't use xargs because it not allow ar at the blacklist.

Comment: @LeeGunMo Then your blacklist is incomplete because `xargs` doesn't appear in there - please make sure your question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`** (`backtick`) in the following way:

```
head `ls -1`
```

> Backtick  has a very special meaning. Everything you type between
>   backticks is evaluated (executed) by the shell before the main command
>
> So the command will do the following:
>
> `ls -1` - will result with the file names
>
> head - will show the start of the files listed in `ls -1`

More info about *backtick* can be found in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27432/215641)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a glob that matches `flag.txt` but can use neither `*` not the string `flag`, you can use `fl[a]g.txt` instead. Then, to print the entire file using `head`, use `-c` and pass it the size of the file:

```
head -c $(stat -c '%s' fl[a]g.txt) fl[a]g.txt
```

Another approach would be to use the shell to read the file:

```
while IFS=  read -r c; do echo $c; done < fl[a]g.txt
```

You could also just use `paste`:

```
paste fl[a]g.txt
```